# Add inverted quotes to a value of a variable in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I would like to have a variable value as "1/14/2013 10:00:00" (including the inverted quotes). Below is the code:

```
$a = Get-Date
$b = $a.AddDays(-1)
$b = $b.ToShortDateString();
$StartTime = "10:00:00 PM"
$EndTime = "11:00:00 PM"
$before = $b + " " + $StartTime
$after = $b + " " + $EndTime
```

Upon further research, I found that there is an issue reported by Microsoft. It can be found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/376207/executing-commands-which-require-quotes-and-variables-is-practically-impossible#details)

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: not sure I follow your issue.. isn't surrounding string with single quotes enough? $StartTime = '"10:00:00 PM"' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you still need to use variables in your string you can use escaped quotes e.g.:

```
PS> $before = "`"$b $EndTime`""
PS> $before
"1/14/2013 11:00:00 PM"
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, I am trying to filter the event log for a server. When i use this method, powershell points out to conversion error for date time format. Is it possible to convert the variable to datetime format while retaining the quotes?

Comment: I used: `$before = [datetime]$before`

Comment: No I don't think the DateTime.Parse/TryParse methods will go for that.

Comment: It works. I am able to pull information by using this variable with Get-EventLog cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include doubleqoutes in your string, wrap the string with single quotes `' '`. If you need single questions, you wrap string with doublequotes. Ex.:

```
$StartTime = '"10:00:00 PM"'
```

Output:

```
[13:00:38] PS-ADMIN > $StartTime
"10:00:00 PM"
```